# Kendo Grid not loading remote JSON data

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I've searched the many articles on SO already as well as from the telerik site but I'm still running into the issue where my data will not load.

Here is the Kendo grid in JS:

```
$("#ss-address-book-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: "http://localhost:65257/InternalDirect/GetAddresses"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    alias: { type: "string" },
                    full_address: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    columns:
    [
        {
            field: "full_address",
            title: "Address"
        },
        {
            field: "alias",
            title: "Alias"
        }
    ]
});
```

I'm attempting to hit an MVC web api - the call and the response received is successful, and in the correct format:

General:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:65257/InternalDirect/GetAddresses
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:125
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 27 Mar 2017 16:21:48 GMT
```

Response:

```
[{"alias":"Test Alias","full_address":"test@directaddy.com"},
{"alias":"Test Alias 2","full_address":"test@directaddy.com 2"}]
```

The kendo grid UI does load; there are no JS errors being thrown.

You can see in the response header I've sent Access-Control_Allow_Origin, given it will be cross-domain. The response seems to be in the correct format.

I've changed the 'type' to be odata and jsonp. I've also set the datatype in the read section to json/jsonp.

Anyone have ideas on this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - I needed to define a data header and an ID - the following changed JS in the schema section:

```
 schema: {
      data: "Data",
      model: {
         id: "full_address",
         fields: {
              alias: { type: "string" },
              full_address: { type: "string" }
         }
...
```

And the following changes to the JSON object returned:

```
{"Data":[
    {
      "alias":"Test Alias",
      "full_address":"test@directaddy.com"
    },
    {
      "alias":"Test Alias 2",
      "full_address":"test2@directaddy.com"
    }]}
```